# Second pass at probability theory, asking for a book

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Recently I've begun revisiting my old probability theory lecture notes. Let's keep it discrete for now. I'm trying to do stuff like this:

> What is conditional probability? It's the probability of $E$ given that $F$ happens. The formula is $\mathbb{P}(E|F) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(E \cap F)}{\mathbb{P}(F)}$, given $\mathbb{P}(F) > 0$.

Instead of fiddling with formulae (I don't even know why it was introduced like this), I can of course just consider the current probability space triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, transform $\mathcal{F}$ into $\mathcal{F'}$ (which really is just taking a sub-$\sigma$-algebra) and re-assigning/distributing the weights (the measure of each element in the $\sigma$-algebra).

I'm wondering if there are literature that treats probability theory more in a fundamental level like this? Such as building the model of probability theory, giving a deeper understanding of concepts.

Comment: This is a special case of conditional expectations.  Measure theoretic probability books cover conditional expectation. See Klenke's book or Durrett's book.

Comment: @Mason well that was not what I mean. What I'm trying to say is, fundamentally you can understand (at least the basics, the building blocks) without using functions, rather just using the construction. I dodged measure theory throughout uni, and I'm using 'measure' liberally here. I'm using measure as in 'count how many of the total is relevant', not in an actual measure theoretic way. I'm not asking for conditional probabilities specifically (I've studied Durrett's EOSP book though, loved it).

Comment: At least I think for discrete probalities, you can just use the construction and do the rest with combinatorics, counting 'good' events from $\mathcal{F}$ and taking the total weight of the 'good' events.

Comment: Check Shiryaev's Probability-1 book, the first 100 or so pages.

Comment: If you've already had a first pass at probability, I suggest just doing it right on the second pass -- i.e. a measure theoretic treatment. If you haven't had measure theory, no problem. Books like Billingsley's "Probability and Measure" (a classic) will teach you along the way.